Is There Work Done By Friction On A Foot While Walking?
A person is walking at an accelerating speed of 1 m/s^2. Assume only friction between the ground and the feet provides the horizontal force for acceleration. The person weighs 60 kg and starts from rest. They walk 0.2 meter. What is the total work done by friction between a foot and ground?
Initially, it seems like the answer is 60N*0.2m=12J, since friction is providing the force for the acceleration. However, I am confused because it could also be argued that the total work done by friction is 0, since the foot does not move relative to the ground while in contact (static friction does no work).
I would greatly appreciate any clarification to resolve this apparent contradiction.

No work is done by the foot on the ground, but work is done by the foot on the center of mass of the body. A human being walking is a poor choice for visualizing the physics here. Picture instead a treaded vehicle like the Mars rover or a tank, and the answer will be the same.

When a person walks with constant speed, net friction force due to ground on their feet acts in direction of their velocity, to counteract the force of resistance due to air.
Work of a force is defined as dot product of the force vector and displacement vector of the subject of force; if using single-dimensional components, it is equal to magnitude of force times displacement in direction of this force.
In the frame of the ground, since the foot does not undergo any displacement while touching the ground, the displacement of the foot is zero, and thus friction force of the ground does zero work on the foot. Magnitude of gravity or friction force (which is different from gravity force) is immaterial; zero displacement, zero work.
In the frame of the walking person, things are different: the foot on the ground and the ground itself both move with respect to the person center of mass, and direction of displacement of the foot is opposite to friction force from the ground on the foot. Consequently, in this frame, the ground does negative work on the foot, and the foot does positive work on the ground. This may seem strange, but it is not; it is consistent with the fact the person, in his/her own frame, does work when walking; a part (smaller) of this work goes to the ground, and the other part (major) turns into internal energy, manifested as increased temperature of muscles.
Value and sign of work, and also kinetic energy and its change, are not absolute. They always depend on the frame of reference which we are using to evaluate them.

Thank you for your answer. As I understand, work is change in energy. How can change in energy be different in different reference frames? It doesn't make sense that energy can be different in different reference frames (at least in this context). An analogy I can think of is of a car driving quickly past a person pushing a block. The displacement here would be very big, leading to a lot of work appearing to be done, which does not seems to be the case.

@HerbertTheBird Work is not change in energy. Work of force is defined as force times displacement of the subject of force, there is no relation of this work to kinetic energy. Only when we consider all forces, all displacements, and calculate sum of all works done on the system, this sum of works (net work) equals change of kinetic energy of the system. For the accelerating person, in that sum of all works, there will be internal works due to internal forces acting on moving parts of the body, and sum of these works are positive. The ground does zero work and can be dropped from the sum.

@HerbertTheBird Change of kinetic energy is different in different reference frames, this is a trivial consequence of how kinetic energy is defined: $E_k = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$. Velocity is frame dependent, thus  $E_k$ is frame-dependent, and due to second power, also change of kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2}m(v+\Delta v)^2 - \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is frame-dependent.

@HerbertTheBird In your example, indeed it is the case that work of the person on the block depends on the frame, and is much bigger in the frame of the car. The person does the "same thing" in all frames only if we always mentally transport to the frame of the person, but actually they do different things from the point of view of different frames. In the frame of the person, the block barely moves, so it acquires only small kinetic energy, but in the frame of the car, the block moves with large kinetic energy, and the change due to person is also large.

Let's suppose the box is not moving, but is still being pushed. Since there is displacement and net force on the box, there should be net work. I'm confused because it also seems like the KE of the box doesn't change relative to the car, since its relative velocity stays constant. Thank you for your help.

If the box is not moving wrt ground while the person pushes it, then there has to be opposing force on the box due to ground. In the frame of the car, the force due to person does positive work, and the force due to ground does negative work of equal magnitude, so net work done on the box is zero. Kinetic energy of the box is constant in all inertial frames, so net work on the box is zero in all inertial frames.
